# Using Wrapper with function pointers to handle default value for arguments

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers, default-value

I have a C++ Wrapper Class for a C Interface. One function in that interface has an argument with a default parameter:

```
api.h:
int Foo(int bar=5);
```

This is the Wrapper:

```
Wrapper.hpp:
class Wrapper
{
public:
   static int (*Foo) (int bar);
}

Wrapper.cpp:
int (*Wrapper::Foo)(int bar);
```

This is where I use the function with the Wrapper:

```
Wrapper::Foo(5);
```

But I also want to be able to call `Foo` without an argument so it takes the default value `5`:

```
Wrapper::Foo();
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do such thing, only with function-pointers, since default arguments are forbidden for function-pointer and you cannot assign function `int(int)` to function `int()`.

N3376 8.3.6/3

> A default argument shall be specified only in the parameter-declaration-clause of a function declaration

Why you want to use pointers? Simply write function, that will call function from API.

```
class Wrapper
{
public:
   static int Foo (int bar) 
   { 
      return ::Foo(bar); 
   }
   static int Foo ()
   {
      return ::Foo();
   }
}

Wrapper::Foo(1);
Wrapper::Foo();
```

Comment: Beware however that you have no guarantee that the default values used in the wrapper are the same as in the API, especially if you don't have control over the API and the default value may change at any time.

Comment: @arne agree. now there is no such problem.